# matching restrictions in regex, when a match satisfies another

Tags: regex

i have a string that can look like the following

```
id=16&xxx&sid=3
xxx&sid=3&id=5
xxx&xxx&id=6
sid=5&xxxx
```

basicly , there is `id` and `sid` and i want to parse their values with regex but the problem is both end with "id"

i have the following regex

```
ssid=(\d{1,})
id=(\d{1,})
```

what can i do to the second expression  `id=(\d{1,})` it considers  ss(id)=x a match.
what can i do to solve this problem considering that i don't know what comes before the expression?

how can i do something like consider it a match as long as its not preceded by `ss`

Comment: Can you use two patterns?

Comment: @progenhard yes i can

Comment: Also 16&xxx is this considered the value for id in your first example or is it just 16. Is there a particular constraints to the values for example?

Comment: @progenhard just the number xxx is a string that i don't care about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/(?:^|[^s])id=(\d+)/` will match unless preceded by an s

The first part fo the regex: `(?:^|[^s])` mean "match the start of the string or anything but an s"

You'll also notice i switched the `\d{1,}` to `\d+` since they do the same thing

Update:

since it is not "sid" you are trying to avoid, but "ssid", use this instead:

`/(?:^|[^s])s?id=(\d+)/`

This will match sid, but not ssid, if that is what you need

Answer (score 1):

```
   (?:[^s]|^)(?:s?id)=(\d*)?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/eRO4xjz2W-fKdcWf)

Answer (score 1):

Since this looks like the query parameter list of an URL, I assume it is one.

I do not think that a single regular expression is the best matched solution for this.  The cleanest and obvious solution is:

- split the string on `&`
- split each part on `=`, create a map
- look up the keys you need in that map

That way, you can trivially use more parameters from that string later.  It also helps for reading the code later and visually verifying its correctness.

This extends to URL handling in general.  Better parse it into a readable structure (whatever that is in your language) and use access functions for the individual parts.  Since the correct escaping and unescaping of URL parts is not trivial, there should be a little library for this.